# sp2010 populate dropdown combo from ECT

Tags: dropdown, external-content-type

I have absolutely struggled in creating a custom control to use an external data source to populate a dropdown combo list.  Does anyone have any good examples of how to implement this?  Is a custom control the best way to go about this?

Note:  I have created some ECT's using the .net bdc model.  I just think the ECT field is a bit non-userfriendly compared to a dropdownlist.

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using InfoPath to customize the list form and connected to an External list as a data source to populate a drop-down list?

Comment: Lori,  I have not heard of InfoPath? I'll do some research on this option today.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable creating a webpart that does this I would recommend giving [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366539.aspx) a read.  Databind from a SQLDataSource or ObjectDataSource to a DropDownList is a fairly common task and there are many resources out there that cover it.  The above link is a good place to start though.

This would also give you the ability to have a custom web part property where you set the datasource for each instance of the web part.

Comment: Abe, I need to populate a dropdown list in the Edit form for a custom list. I don't think a web part inside of an edit form would be the best way to update a listitem.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.